# Where is TestNG report file when running Maven/Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I run TestNG using Maven. I'm trying now to use Jenkins' testng-plugin to see the results.

When I run the tests in Eclipse, I get the file /test-output/testng-results.xml

However I don't see such a file in my Jenkins agent. Where can I find it? and if it is not created, how do I create it?

Comment: What do you see in workspace/target/surefire-reports?  Also the console can also give you a clue.  Are you running as mvn test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please configure project to use custom workspace by providing path of your test source location on remote machine.The reports will be generated inside your custom workspace folder only. Rest is just to add rest of the path in post build action `..\test-output\testng-results.xml`

Comment: I don't understand. You talk about configuring the Jenkins project? It uses a custom workspace. I run the tests with "mvn install", which runs everything, including the tests.
And basically, that is exactly what I did. I have the pom in %WORKSPACE%/some/place/pom.xml, and I tried both %WORKSPACE%/some/place/test-output\testng-results.xml and %WORKSPACE%/some/place/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml.  Neither work.

Comment: please try to search testng-results.xml in your workspace folder and then add the path in post build action excluding %WORKSPACE%. add only relative path like this if workspace directory name is "C:\Test\" and report is generated in "C:\test\test-output\testng-results.xml" than add only "test-output\testng-results.xml" in post build.

Comment: The other answer helped me

Comment: Can any one please help me in resolving the [Click here for question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715103/test-outpput-folder-generated-outside-of-the-base-directory-when-running-test)  issue

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the post-build action "Publish TestNG Results" of the job. And as the "testng xml report pattern", give `**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml`. That should show the results in the job's page.

Comment: That's what I did, and it doesn't find it. What is ** ?

Comment: Can any one please help me in resolving the [Click here for question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715103/test-outpput-folder-generated-outside-of-the-base-directory-when-running-test)  issue